# Upload imagefile from iOS device with objective-c to an PHP

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to upload an image from my iphone (from imagepicker) to my server (with an PHP-script). But how do I get the image from the imagepicker / ImageView to the script for upload?

Here is my database connection code:

```
NSString *brugernavn = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:kBrugernavn];
    NSString *maaltid = self.maaltid.text;
    //NSString *rating = [segmentedControl titleForSegmentAtIndex:[segmentedControl selectedSegmentIndex]];
    //NSString *rating = self.rating;
    NSString *kommentar = self.kommentar.text;
    NSString *place = self.place.text;

    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filepath];

    NSMutableString *urlString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithFormat:@"brugernavn=%@&&maaltid=%@&&kommentar=%@&&place=%@&&thumbnail=%@&&submit",brugernavn,maaltid,kommentar,place,data];
    [urlString appendFormat:@"%@", data];
    NSData *postData = [urlString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding
                               allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];
    NSString *baseurl = @"http://example.com/upload.php";

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:baseurl];

    NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [urlRequest setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
    [urlRequest setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [urlRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
      forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [urlRequest setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self];
    [connection start];
```

And here is my code for the imagepicker:

```
// KAMERA - Aktiverer kameraet ved tryk på knap
- (IBAction)useCamera:(id)sender {
    if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
    {
        UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        imagePicker.delegate = self;
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        imagePicker.mediaTypes = @[(NSString *) kUTTypeImage];
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
        [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
        _newMedia = YES;
    }
}

// KAMERA - Aktiverer kamerarullen ved tryk på knap
- (IBAction)useCameraRoll:(id)sender {
    if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum])
    {
        UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        imagePicker.delegate = self;
        imagePicker.SourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        imagePicker.mediaTypes = @[(NSString *) kUTTypeImage];
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
        [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
        _newMedia = NO;
    }
}

// KAMERA - Sender valgt billede til imageView
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    NSString *mediaType = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    if([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage])
    {
        UIImage *image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
        _imageView.image = image;
        if (_newMedia)
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, @selector(image:finishedSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
    } else if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie])
    {
        // Code here to support video if enabled
    }
}
```

And here the imageView from my .h-file:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
```

And here is the defination of my upload-field on PHP:

```
$_FILES['thumbnail']['name']
```

The user should take a picture og choose from the cameraroll and then write some info like title, description, etc. for the upload and then upload the image and info the server with the PHP-script.

Please help me :o)

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while since I used this, but it worked then :)

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(bilden);

NSString *filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"bild%d%@", bildnr,@".png"];
NSString *urlString = @"http://extranet.pool.se/stockholmsmassan/rita_pa_vaggen/sparabild.php";

// setting up the request object now
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", filename] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:imageData];

// second parameter information
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"epost\"\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[epost dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r \n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// setting the body of the post to the reqeust
[request setHTTPBody:body];

// now lets make the connection to the web
NSURLResponse* response;
NSError* error;
NSData* result = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:result encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];  
NSLog(@"return: %@",returnString);
```

Comment: But 'bilden' and 'bildnr' - how did you set them? Right now I just have my picture in a imageView! Se code above...

Comment: Bilden is an UIImage so you can use your "image". Bildnr doesn't matter since you can call your file whatever you like.

Comment: Something is happend when I use these code: `NSData *imageData;
    imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView.image, 90);
    
    NSString *filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"bild.png"];` how did your php uploading-script looks like, because right now, it looks like the image is uploading. The scripe runs (the log tells me), but nothing is being posted to the database!